# Access various columns with regex in dataframe

Tags: regex, r

I have a Dataframe which I access like this:

```
someC <- myDf[, c("abcdefg", "hij_klm")]
```

I need the regex equivalent to this operation. 
I thought about something like

```
someB <- myDf[, c(grep("abc", names(myDf)), grep("hij", names(myDf)))]
```

But that seems wrong.

Thats how `myDf` looks like (random columnnames)

```
qwe_rtz    ui_pa    sdf_gh    hjkl    abcdefg    hij_klm
1          2        3         4       5          6
a          b        c         d       e          f
...        ...      ...       ...     ...        ...
```

I want to grab the columns `abcdefg` and `hij_klm`. The output must be the same as if I would access the columns with `myDf[, c("abcdefg", "hij_klm")]`.

As a identifier I can use the first three characters, withthe specific order of the characters `abc` and `hij`. 
How to do that with regex?

Note: I must use the specifid combination of the characters. So basically I want to search within a string for characters, in a specific order.

Comment: Cannot you grep `def`?

Comment: @Pascal what do you mean?

Comment: The common pattern of `c("cccdef1", "bbbdef2")` is `def`.

Comment: or `pattern = "(bbb)|(ccc)"` if you just want to be able to search using an `or`

Comment: @Pascal ah, I understand. No, I need to search for `ccc` and `bbb` and the output must be exactly the same as doing it with `c()`.

Comment: From your question, it wasn't clear at all

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand then. If you could add a minimal reproducible example and expected output, it may clear things up.